# Making a wrapper div's width relative to the contents

Tags: html, css

I need your help.

How can the "wrap"'s div width be re-sized such that its width is relative to the other contents that are in it. Right now it appears to be automatically 100%?

Here's a pic of the problem:
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#icon {
    background: url("images/glass.png") no-repeat left;
    width: 20px;
    float: left;
}
#txt1 {
    width: 150px;
    border: none;
}
#wrap {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: auto;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>

    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="icon"></div>
        <div><input id="txt1" type="text"/></div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried #wrap{display:inline;}?

Comment: Firstly; make a JSFiddle, it makes it much easier for folks to help you. Secondly; that's what `<div>` elements *do*, they're block level. Consider using a `<span>` instead.

Comment: If I use a <span>, its still the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `display: inline-block;`.

```
#wrap {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should go like this i guess:

```
<div style="width:400px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, elements with `display: block` will occupy the entire width available. Try using this:

```
display: inline-block;
```

However, this will cause that your `div` will no longer cause a line break, so you may have to insert a `<br>` element

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` element is by default block level and will use 100% of the available width unless you style it not to. You'll have to set its `display` CSS property to `inline-block` in order for it to expand according to the elements inside it.